# Two map views should be displayed in a fragment on after the other from one MapActivity

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-fragments

I have two panes(left side list and right side details) in my android tablet application(just like Settings native tablet app view). I have extended MapActivity to my MainActivity. and I have a list of location details left side. I wanted to display the MapView for each list item in my right pane which is a fragment.

The problem is when I try to open Map View, for the first item it is opening mapView. From second item onwards it is showing you can only open one MapView for one MapActivity. Please suggest a right answer.  I have tried all the related posts but of no success.

My code version : android 4.0

Please check the below code :

```
    MainActivity extends MapActivity {
    onCreate(){
                    LocationFragment loc_fragment=new LocationFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction xaction=VenueFragment.venueFrgMgr.beginTransaction();
                    Bundle sendData=new Bundle();
                    sendData.putString("LAT", s.getLat());
                    sendData.putString("LON", s.getLong());
                    sendData.putString("NAME", s.getName());
                    sendData.putString("ADD", s.getAddress());
                    loc_fragment.setArguments(sendData);
                    xaction.add(R.id.second_pane, loc_fragment,"location");
                    xaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);

                    xaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    xaction.commit();

   }
 @Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {

    return false;
}
```

}

code for LocationFragment which shows MapView is below :

```
    private ViewGroup mapContainer;
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            //view.refreshDrawableState();

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location, container, false);
            mapContainer=new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            mapContainer.addView(view);
            v = view.findViewById(R.id.loading);
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    /*      lonstr=LocationActivity.lonstr;
            latstr=LocationActivity.latstr;
            name=LocationActivity.name;
            address=LocationActivity.address;
    */      
            ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.back))
                    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            //getActivity().finish();
                            if(mapView != null) {
                                mapView.removeAllViewsInLayout();

                                if(mapContainer!=null)
                                    mapContainer.removeView(mapView);

                                RelativeLayout parentView = (RelativeLayout) mapView.getParent();
                                //mapView.removeAllViews();
                                ((MapView)view.findViewById(R.id.mapview)).removeAllViews();
                                parentView.removeAllViews();
                                if(parentView!=null)
                                    parentView.recomputeViewAttributes(mapView);
                                getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("location").getView().destroyDrawingCache();
                            }

                            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                        //  getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                        }
                    });
            mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);

            mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            mc = mapView.getController();


            Bundle b = this.getArguments();
            if (b != null) {
                latstr = b.getString("LAT");
                lonstr = b.getString("LON");
                name = b.getString("NAME");
                address = b.getString("ADD");
            }

            String coordinates[] = { latstr, lonstr };
            try {
                lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
                lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
            mc.animateTo(p);
            Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red_pin);
            icon.setBounds(0, 0, icon.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                    icon.getIntrinsicHeight());
            MyItemizedOverlay overlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(icon);
            OverlayItem item = new OverlayItem(p, "", null);
            overlay.addItem(item);
            overlay.populateNow();
            mapView.getOverlays().add(overlay);
            mapView.postInvalidate();
            mc.setZoom(12);
            if (name != null)
                ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_name)).setText(name);
            if (address != null)
                ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_date)).setText(address);
            getWheather();

            return mapContainer;
        }
```

Error I am getting is below :

```
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #184: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at webspiders.event2mobile.asme.LocationFragment.onCreateView(LocationFragment.java:128)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:828)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     ... 19 more
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You are only allowed to have a single MapView in a MapActivity
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.setupMapView(MapActivity.java:397)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:289)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:264)
10-15 10:43:03.881: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:247)
```

Comment: you don't need a new mapview for each location. just refresh your current one with new data

Comment: how could I do it, could you please post a sample code

Comment: @Tomislav Novoselec, can you please enhance your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have in your MainActivity one listview, and one container which holds your mapview.

And when item is selected in listivew, you would like to do something on your map.

If so, then you need only one fragment which holds your map, and then each time when a new item is selected from your list, you need to inform your fragment that a new data is available, and it should refresh itself.

You can do it via custom interface, if you know how to create one.

Answer (score 0):

```
I resolved the problem like this, by creating map object in Activity class and using it in Fragments. Here the code goes  

In ACTIVITY 

    HomeActivity extends MapActivity {
            View mMapViewContainer;
            MapView mMapView;

        onCreate(){
    ------------
    -------------
          mMapViewContainer = (ViewGroup)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.location, null);
          mMapView = (MapView) mMapViewContainer.findViewById(R.id.mapview);

    -------------
    ---------------
       }
     @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {

        return false;
    }


    In Fragment:


            HomeActivity parentActivity = (HomeActivity) getActivity();
            if (parentActivity != null) {
                parentActivity.mMapViewContainer.refreshDrawableState();
                mMapViewContainer = parentActivity.mMapViewContainer;
                mMapView = parentActivity.mMapView;

                mMapView.getOverlays().clear();
                mMapView.invalidate();

            }
```